# What is "PARALLEL BUILD" in docker hub private registry?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-registry

While trying to signup with docker hub by selecting a suitable plan, I see pricing is based on Private Repositories Required and Parallel Builds desired.

What is a PARALLEL BUILD in this context?

PS: 
After a bit of an internet search, I found that docker hub can pull up my source code from external repositories and build an image by itself and later publish the same into Hub. If this is true and I don't want to use docker hub build service, can I ignore the PARALLEL BUILD part entirely?

Comment: The parallelism is across all of the repos owned by you when build, so you can ignore as you don't need build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/) is a service provided by Docker for finding and sharing container images with your team. It provides the following major features:

- Repositories: Push and pull container images.
- Teams & Organizations: Manage access to private repositories of
  container images.
- Official Images: Pull and use high-quality container images provided
  by Docker.
- Publisher Images: Pull and use high-quality container images provided
  by external vendors. Certified images also include support and
  guarantee compatibility with Docker Enterprise.
- Builds: Automatically build container images from GitHub and
  Bitbucket and push them to Docker Hub
- Webhooks: Trigger actions after a successful push to a repository to
  integrate Docker Hub with other services.

More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/).

If you see the [pricing](https://hub.docker.com/pricing) page of dockerhub. There are two things you should know:

- PARALLEL BUILD specifies the number of images that you can build
  parallelly (con-currently). The parallelism is across all of the
  repos owned by you.
- Private Repository specify the number of repository that are private and not exposed publicly.

If you're new to docker and trying out it first time then its ok to go with dockerhub free plan where you can have max 1 private repository and 1 parallel build count.

If you want to store docker images of your project privately that is hosted somewhere on public cloud like AWS then I suggest to use docker registry provided by those cloud providers like [AWS ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/), [Azure ACR](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/container-registry/), [Google container registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/) and so on.

Or else you can host docker image privately by running docker registry inside container. Check [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry).

Hope this helps.

Comment: gr8. What if a build trigger gets called while a build is in progress. Does it get queued and processed sequentially after the completion of the on-going build. Or just the build trigger is ignored while another build is in progress.

Comment: It should be queued.

Comment: With Docker Hub Build, what will docker hub require to build the image... the source code (so that it can build the bins and then use those bins for image build process) OR just directly the bins, from the source repo. ( though i don't think the later will be the case as it's not good practice to put any bins besides the code in a source repo).